# why the emulators have different sizes than the mentioned ones

Tags: android, android-emulator

Why some devices are for example 2.7 inches and when you launch the emulator the real size is not 2.7 inches..?

***Edit:***
And will the display on that screen be like the real display or will it differ on real devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the emulator to have the same number of pixels or to have the same size as the real device. You cannot have both since the density of your screen in general differs from the density of the device.

If you specify to have the same size and the actual size still differs, then your OS did not correctly recognize the density of your screen.

The density of the screen on the development machine is normally lower than the one of the device. A pixel perfect emulation of the device screen will therefore only be achieved when you choose the same pixel size. But then, the emulation is very good since the emulator runs the same code and operating system as the real device.

Answer (score 0):

This you can set while launching the emulator. You will get an option of scaling display to real size but that will appear very small on your computer screen. So better use the default size which fits to the screen.